# ¿Cómo puedo contar elementos String?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa que tiene que salir por pantalla el contenido de la String . Es hasta 10 y tendría que salir por pantalla esto: _1 _ _2 _ _ _3 _ _ _ _4 _ _ _ _ _5 ...(Hasta el 10)

```
private static final String GUION = "_";
private static final String VALOR = "&";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numero = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(GUION);

        for (int j = 2; j < 10; j++) {

            System.out.print(GUION.length());

        }

    }
    for (int j = 1; j < 25; j++) {

        System.out.print(VALOR);

    }

}
```

}

He hecho esto pero lo unico que sale es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo, comentar que las & están bien, no se tiene que hacer nada con ellas. Gracias!!

Comment: `GUION.length()` siempre va a ser 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente no sé para que necesitas los `&` ya que no hablas de ellos en tu pregunta. Sin embargo, tendrías que hacer dos bucles para mostrar lo que necesitas, uno que fuera desde 1 hasta 10 y el segundo bucle que escribiera los guiones. Una vez escritos los guiones tendrías que imprimir el valor correspondiente.

También, tienes que observar que tendrías que mostrar el índice del primer bucle ya que si haces `GUION.length()` siempre te va a dar como resultado el valor 1.

Te dejo tu código corregido. Como puedes observar he eliminado los &:

```
private static final String GUION = "_";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numero = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(GUION);
        }
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Este código te daría el siguiente resultado:

```
_1__2___3____4_____5______6_______7________8_________9__________10
```

Comment: Hola como he dicho en la pregunta, los & solo hacen esa función, por eso no he entrado en detalle. Gracias, ahora pruebo el código :)

Comment: @bpico A vale, no había leído la última línea jajaja